# How to run Hive with Spark Execution Engine (Apache Hive version 2.1.1 and Apache Spark Version 2.2.0)

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

We have switched the Hive execution engine from MapReduce to Spark and trying to run queries in the Hive shell using `beeline` and `jdbc`.

We are able to run simple queries (e.g.: `select * from table`) as it doesn't require processing of the data, but when we try to run queries that contain aggregation functions (e.g.: `select count(*) from table`) we are facing the following error:

```
Query ID = hadoop_20180105123047_5bcd0d7a-78bd-4b66-b5fb-fc430726c2a9
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first query works is because it does not need any MR or Spark jobs to run. The HS2 or Hive client just read the data directly. The second query requires MR or Spark jobs to be ran. This is key to remember when testing or troubleshooting the cluster.

Are you able to run Spark jobs out side of Hive?

Comment: Yes,we are able to run the spark jobs outside the Hive. Even we have upgraded the Hive version to Hive-2.3.2 and still not able to connect spark client while running the queries in Hive shell.